# SQL Select from two tables with Prio

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  a.name
FROM table1 a, table2 t
WHERE a.id = t.id

What I actually get: 
id | name
1  | Foo
1  | Bar  
2  | Bar
```

I want the following results:

- If Foo exists I want foo as result.
- If Foo does not exists then Bar

So that prio 1 is foo, and prio 2 is bar.

```
id | name
1  | Foo 
2  | Bar
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Specify the table data as well.

Comment: What do you mean with "exists"? You are doing an inner join, so a record will always exist in both tables.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) which you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way seems to be:

```
SELECT
  t.id, a.name
FROM table1 a, table2 t
WHERE 
  (a.id = t.id and a.name = 'Foo')
OR 
  (a.id = t.id and a.name = 'Bar' 
   and t.id not in (SELECT id from table1 x where x.name ='Foo')
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb2c86/1

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following by using suggested [*ANSI JOIN syntax*](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/9169/Join-types-and-their-implementation-using-ANSI-JOIN-syntax-in-Oracle.html) :

```
SELECT t.id, max(a.name) name
  FROM table1 a JOIN table2 t on ( a.id = t.id ) 
GROUP BY t.id;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9497/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a `join` for this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.name = 'Foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.name = 'Bar' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 aa WHERE aa.id = a.id AND aa.name = 'Foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ranking* function if your *DBMS* support

```
select t.*
from (SELECT t.id, a.name,
             row_number() over (partition by t.id 
                                order by (case when a.name = 'Foo' then 0 
                                               when a.name = 'Bar' then 1 
                                               else 2 
                                           end)) Seq
      FROM table1 a 
      inner join table2 t on a.id = t.id 
      ) t
where Seq = 1;
```